# button background image is flipped

Tags: android, image, button

Really odd behaviour. I have a simple layout, 4 image views in one column that match up with 4 buttons on next column. I've used a gradient (subtle) background image - going from darker to lighter left to right.

The image view background image displays correctly, in that it has the darker color background as it's the left side of the background image. However the button background image is reversed with gradient going in the opposite direction.

Both the image and button views use the same background image. I can not understand why the background image is flipped on the button. Any ideas?

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".IndexMenuActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0sp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:background="@drawable/redbkg"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/i_ax" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:background="@drawable/bluebkg"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/i_mx" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:background="@drawable/greenbkg"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/i_ref" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:background="@drawable/yellowbkg"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/i_cal" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="75dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:background="@drawable/redbkg"
        android:onClick="subjectListMx"
        android:text="ASSESSMENT"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="34sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:background="@drawable/bluebkg"
        android:onClick="subjectListMx"
        android:text="MANAGEMENT"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="34sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:background="@drawable/greenbkg"
        android:onClick="subjectListRef"
        android:text="REFERENCE"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="34sp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:background="@drawable/yellowbkg"
        android:onClick="subjectListCal"
        android:text="CALCULATOR"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="34sp"/>
</LinearLayout></androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: Note the gradient don't match]

Answer (score 0):

Using a color meter, it does not appear that there's any flipping going on; the gradient starts with a lighter color on the left and moves to a darker color on the right for both the background of the image and the background of the text.

The problem is that you have two different gradients, so you go from light to dark and then light to dark again. You probably want to apply a single gradient to both views.

Comment: Thanks. However the background image definitely goes from dark to light, left to right. I’ve used it elsewhere and can confirm this. So the image is being flipped. 

Clearly flipping on both